# TFS2010 Build does not run unit tests

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a build definition in TFS2010, I queue the build manually and set Disable Tests flag to False.
However, my unit tests are still not getting run. I reviewed the xaml file and it appears fine. The configuration used for the build is "Release".
Is there something else that needs to be done?
Unit test related snippet:

> ```
> if Condition="[Not DisableTests]" DisplayName="If Not DisableTests"
> ```
>
> sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="1178,2157"
>   mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some of the build file. Most likely you are either a) missing the custom action to run the tests or b) it is improperly configured.

Answer (score 1):

Check the build definition properity "DisableTests" should be set to false.